# (Python 3, BeautifulSoup 4) - Scraping Pagination in Div

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can scrape the first page of this site:

http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/1/10

But I am trying to scrape all the other pages on the site by using the "Next" button in the pagination of the site.

I have clicked the Next button and I can see that the parameter that changes is from 0/1/10 to 0/2/10 for page 2 and so on.

I have looked at the pagination code and I can see that the pagination is in a Div

```
 <div id="pagingNext" class="link-wrapper">
```

The issue is I have only successfully scraped pagination from another site using the code below:

```
button_next = soup.find("a", {"class": "btn paging-next"}, href=True)
while button_next:
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don't get kicked by server
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://www.propertypal.com{0}".format(button_next["href"]))
```

This worked, but as this site I am currently scraping doesn't seem to provide a a href for the Next Button URL I am lost as to how to try and scrape it

I tried:

```
button_next = soup.find("div", {"class": "paging-Next"})
while button_next:
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don't get kicked by server
    soup=makesoup(url = "https://www.propertypal.com{0}".format(button_next))
```

But it just doesn't seem to scrape the other pages, just the first page still.

If anyone can provide help I would be extremely appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll need `Selenium` for this one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to verify `button_next` url since you already know how the urls change accross all pages. So, instead of using url "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/1/10" I'd recommend using "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/1/50", the website provides this option for seeing 50 items at once, so instead of iterating through 4044 you are only going through 809 pages.

In the while loop we are waiting for  `current` to be 810, so we know the last page was scraped because by inspection, `/809/50` is the last page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

current = 0
while current < 810:  # Last page, by inspection is /809/50
    url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/{:d}/50".format(current)
    data = requests.get(url).text 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
    print(url)
    current += 1
    #  Do your scraping here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more thing, let's say that the town I a scraping next time only has 4 pages for example of restaurant data, will the code above look through the 809 pages every time or is it possible for the loop to stop when it has reached the maximum amount of pages, e.g. 4 pages, instead of having to loop through another 825 pages of non existent links?

Comment: Sure, `requests.get("http://www.thispagedoesntexists.com")` returns an error, and therefore you won't even get the text, a good solution is adding a try, exception, statement, so you catch when the page doesn't exist instead of just the error stopping your code.

Comment: In short you can use `response.status_code != 200` to break the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, one thing is I tried to put in the following page below which shows "No Results" as there are only around 4000 pages of restaurants in London, but it seems that it still gives a HTTP 200 response code. Am I right in thinking that this means that pages with no results will still appear to exist to the scraper, and the code to break the loop will not run?      Link to page with no results is http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/6000/10

Comment: In that case use the page content, eg: `"No Results" in response.text`.

Answer (score 3):

workaround:

while you have `True` in your check of `Next` button, you can manually create links and open them in loop by incrementing numeric tail, like you wrote: from 0/1/10 to 0/2/10 for page 2 and so on.

something like this:

```
base_ur = 'http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/' # deleting 1/10

incr = 0
while button_next:
    incr+=1
    next_url = base_url + str(incr)+'/10'
    page = urllib.requests.urlopen(next_url)
    (and then scraping goes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one more thing, let's say that the town I a scraping next time only has 4 pages for example of restaurant data, will the code above look through the 809 pages every time or is it possible for the loop to stop when it has reached the maximum amount of pages, e.g. 4 pages, instead of having to loop through another 825 pages of non existent links?   edit   delete

Comment: in this case when you want to process limited number of pages (and you know this amount of pages) I'd replace `while` loop of `for`

Answer (score 1):

This is the best approach in this case to exhaust all the pages without even knowing how many pages It has spread across as sir t.m.adam has already mentioned. Give this a try. It'll give you all the names.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

target_url = url = "http://ratings.food.gov.uk/enhanced-search/en-GB/%5E/London/Relevance/0/%5E/%5E/0/{}/10"

page_num = 1
while True:
    response = requests.get(target_url.format(page_num))
    if response.status_code == 404: # break once the page is not found
        break
    print("Scraping Page Number {}".format(page_num))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.findAll("div",class_="ResultsBusinessName"):
        name = item.findAll("a")[0].text
        print(name.strip())

    page_num += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One question I don't see a 404 being shown on the page when there are no results on the page. There is just a message saying "No results Found". As t.m.adam has mentioned looking for this message in response.text should work. So if I changed the if statement to   response = requests.get(target_url.format(page_num))
    if response.text == "No results Found": # break once the page is not found
        break.           --Would this be a possible solution?

Comment: @Brendan Rodgers, I'm seriously confused what are you trying to achieve from this thread. Too many answers and most of them are satisfactory. Btw, why do you wanna see 404 message cause whenever the scraper finds no more pages to parse it will automatically break the loop satisfying your requirement.

Comment: I am not wanting to see 404 message. I was just unsure as to if a 404 message is displayed when there are no results found, as when I visited a page with no results it still sent a 200 status even though there was no results to scrape.

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, just trying to get my head around this.